# Draw a line using buttons as a coordinates on a PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates, picturebox

Currently I am making a searching program for Rooms/Office based on the image shown.

[image]

I am having trouble on the program that I want show a line on the 2D map where buttons will be use to connect each coordinates of the line. But after searching a room  no lines that will appear.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Pen myPen;
        myPen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Red, 5);
        System.Drawing.Graphics frmGraphics = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();

        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to Search!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {

                if(textBox1.Text == "dental clinic")
                {


                    frmGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, path1.Location.X, path1.Location.Y, path2.Location.X, path2.Location.Y);
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    frmGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, path2.Location.X, path2.Location.Y, path3.Location.X, path3.Location.Y);
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    frmGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, path3.Location.X, path3.Location.Y, path4.Location.X, path4.Location.Y);


                    lbres.Text = "Dental Clinic";
                    lbloc.Text = "OutPatient Department";
                    OPDView opdfrm = new OPDView();
                    dview = opdfrm;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No Results Found!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                }
                myPen.Dispose();
                frmGraphics.Dispose(); 
                return;

          }
       }
```

I have 4 buttons which a had rename as path1 - path4 and wish to connect them all on the line. I need some help about this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has more issues but I'll only hint at them at the end..

The error you probably trip on is in not getting the coordinates right.

`PictureBox` is not a container control, so whatever you put on **top** of it is **not** sitting **inside** it. Test by moving the PB: The `Buttons` **won't move** with it.. - Note that this is different from putting a `Button` onto a `Panel` or a `GroupBox`..

There are two ways to fix it:

- You can make the `Buttons` children of the `PictureBox` in code or
- You can calculate the correct positions.

Here is how to make the Button children of the PB:

```
path1.Parent = pictureBox1;    
path2.Parent = pictureBox1;    
path3.Parent = pictureBox1;
```

Note that you will have to adopt the code that moces the buttons now

Or you correct the position taking the PB's location into account:

```
Point np1 = Point.Subtract(path1.Location, (Size)pictureBox1.Location);
Point np2 = Point.Subtract(path2.Location, (Size)pictureBox1.Location);
Point np3 = Point.Subtract(path3.Location, (Size)pictureBox1.Location);
frmGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, Point.Empty, np1 , np2);
...
```

Another issue is thatthe way to draw, using `control.CreateGraphics` is not persistent. In fact it is almost always wrong! The results will disappear at each window resize etc.. The better way is to draw in the `Picturebox.Paint` event using the `e.Graphics` parameter.

I also wonder what the `Buttons` are there for in the first place? You can create a `List<Point>` and draw without them just as well.

Also using `Thread.Sleep(500)` for an animation will freeze the UI thread. Instead use a `Timer` to go through the list of points. It you need a fixed number of ways to animate you can create a `Dictionary<string, List<Point>>` to hold them all..

**Update**

To create a list of points is simple. Declare it at class level:

```
List<Point> way = new List<Point>();
```

And fill it when you know the data:

```
way.Add(new Point(100, 100));
way.Add(new Point(150, 100));
way.Add(new Point(150, 200));
way.Add(new Point(10, 200));
way.Add(new Point(10, 220));
way.Add(new Point(50, 220));
way.Add(new Point(50, 250));
```

Also create a Timer and set its Interval. In its Tick event you move up a pointer to the current segment and call the Paint event be invalidating the PictureBox:

```
void aTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    point = Math.Min(point + 1, way.Count);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    if (point >= way.Count) aTimer.Stop();
}
```

And in the Paint event of the PictureBox you draw the path from start to the current index:

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.DarkGoldenrod, 2.5f))
        for (int i = 1; i < point; i++) e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen , way[i - 1], way[i]);
}
```

I left out a few checks and you will want to think of a way to store or construct the point lists..

You also may want to improve the animation by drawing smaller segments. For this you could add more points but using a function will be more flexible..:

```
int stepLen = 10;  // draw 10 pixels on each tick

List<Point> SlowWay(List<Point> way)
{
    List<Point> slow = new List<Point>();

    for (int i = 1; i < way.Count; i++ )
    {
        int dx = way[i].X - way[i - 1].X;
        int dy = way[i].Y - way[i - 1].Y;
        float len = (float)Math.Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        int stepCount = (int)(len / stepLen);
        float stepX = dx / stepCount;
        float stepY = dy / stepCount;

        slow.Add(way[i - 1]);
        for (int s = 0; s < stepCount; s++)
            slow.Add(new Point((int)(way[i - 1].X + s * stepX), 
                               (int)(way[i - 1].Y + s * stepY)));
    }
    slow.Add(way[way.Count - 1]);
    return slow;
}
```

[image]

Comment: It's seems that the only way to connect those lines for which I have been confused is the **Calculate the positions** and the PB's location.

I put buttons so that it will be easier for me to locate each rooms, probably that my mistake and I am trying to re-edit the program based on your answer. Thanks for the help sir.

Comment: If you have problems, just ask! How do you set the button positions? are they fixed? I would definitely go for a List of Points and do the Drawing with the buttons, unless they serve another funtion in the UI.. You can create such a list in a test mode by logging the e.location in a MouseClick event.

Comment: The lines can connect now to the buttons but I am still confuse on the thing that the line will not disappear after I search again another rooms and show the new lines or the path way again. Can you show me a snippet for creating a list?

Comment: Yes, but please try to answer all questions! How do you place or move the buttons now? How many ways are there on the map?

Comment: I have added code for a simple animation, see if you like it.

Comment: I place each buttons on the path ways of each squares on the PB but I didn't want to move the buttons it has a particular placement of each. I think there are 20 paths on the map. The animation look really nice.