# Inconsistency when generating rectangles

Tags: c#, graphics, rectangles

for my application I need to 'detect' barcodes on an invoice. To do this, I draw a rectangle around the first occurance of a barcode, then I draw a rectangle between the first and second occurance, to save its height as the distance between the barcodes, and lastly, I have C# generate additional rectangles around the remaining barcodes, using the first rectangle as a template, and the second as a measurement of distance between barcodes. My problem here is that the rectangles that C# is generating are inconsistent with what I had defined prior.

Under the assumption that the inconsistency was a lineair increase, I tried to use Y=AX+B to counteract the inconsistency, but this only works on one specific invoice, when I try it on a different on, it remains inconsistent.

First, I use mouse events to draw rectangles. I use this code for all of the rectangles that I draw myself:

```
        private void PbPreview_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             When the left mouse button is pressed, the mouseown bool will be set to true, which enables to program to start drawing the rectangle. The current location of the cursor is saved in the XY variable.
             */
            IsMouseDown = true;

            XY = e.Location;
        }

        private void PbPreview_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             When the mouse is released, the current location of the cursor is saved in a seperate variable (X1Y1). These two variables will be used to draw the actual rectangle.
             */
            if (IsMouseDown)
            {
                X1Y2 = e.Location;
                IsMouseDown = false;
                First = false;
                if (Updated)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Ding is bijgewerkt");
                    Updated = false;
                }
            }
            if (Rect != null)
            {
                try
                {

                    bool AfstandGemeten;
                    Bitmap SRC = new Bitmap(PbPreview.Image, PbPreview.Width, PbPreview.Height);
/*
The GaanWeAfstandMeten bool determines if you are drawing the first or second rectangle. If the second rectangle has been drawn, the AfstandGemeten Bool will be set to true, enabeling the program to start generating the remaining rectangles.
*/
                    if (!GaanWeAfstandMeten)
                    {
                        AfstandGemeten = false;
                        GaanWeAfstandMeten = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        AfstandGemeten = true;
                        GaanWeAfstandMeten = false;
                    }

                    /*
                     When all required items have been marked and the distance has been defined, the function to generate the remaining rectangles is called.
                     */
                    if (Index == CheckedOnderdelen().Count && AfstandGemeten)
                    {
                        GetProducten(Afstand);
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception E)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het bijsnijden van de afbeelding." + E.Message);
                }


            }
        }

        private void PbPreview_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            /*
             When the user moves the cursor while the left mouse button is pressed, the current location of the cursor is saved in X1Y1. The XY and X1Y1 variables are used to draw te rectangle.
             */
            if (IsMouseDown)
            {
                X1Y2 = e.Location;

                Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void PbPreview_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            /*
             In case the rectangle is initialised, the function to draw the rectangle is called. The color of the rectangle will differ depending on wether it is the first, second or debug rectangle.
             */
            if(Rect != null)
            {
                if (!GaanWeAfstandMeten)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, GetRect());
                    First = true;
                    DebugLabel.Text = BackupRect.Size.ToString();
                }
                else if (Fixing)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Coral, GetRect());
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Blue, GetRect());
                    Afstand = Rect.Height;
                    DebugLabel.Text = Afstand.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
```

Second, here is the function that is called to draw the rectangle:

```
        public Rectangle GetRect()
            /*
            Function to define the rectangle.
            */
        {
            Rect = new Rectangle();
            Rect.X = Math.Min(XY.X, X1Y2.X);
            Rect.Y = Math.Min(XY.Y, X1Y2.Y);

            Rect.Width = Math.Abs(XY.X - X1Y2.X);
            Rect.Height = Math.Abs(XY.Y - X1Y2.Y);
            /*
            In case it's the first rectangle that is being drawn, its properties are being saved in a backup rectangle to make sure it won't be overwritten when the second rectangle is drawn.
            */
            if (First)
            {
                BackupRect = new Rectangle();
                //BackupRect = Rect;
                BackupRect.X = Rect.X;
                BackupRect.Y = Rect.Y;
                BackupRect.Width = Rect.Width;
                BackupRect.Height = Rect.Height;

                Updated = true;
            }
            /* 
Same deal as above
            */
            if (Fixing)
            {
                FixtRect = new Rectangle();
                FixtRect.X = Rect.X;
                FixtRect.Y = Rect.Y;
                FixtRect.Width = Rect.Width;
                FixtRect.Height = Rect.Height;
            }
            return Rect;
        }
```

And lastly, the function to generate the remaining rectangles:

```
 public List<Bitmap> GetProducten(int ItemAfstand)
        {
            List<Bitmap> Output = new List<Bitmap>();
            foreach (Bitmap B in Set)
            {
                int         LocationX   =           Rect.X;
                int         LocationY   =           Rect.Y;
                Bitmap      Next        =           new Bitmap(Rect.Width, Rect.Height);
                Graphics    G           =           Graphics.FromImage(WorkImage[PreviewIndex]);
                Graphics    J           =           Graphics.FromImage(Next);
                bool        Finished    =           false;
                BackupRect.Height       +=          10;
                ItemAfstand             +=          30;
                GaanWeAfstandMeten       =          true;
                pen = new Pen(Color.Red);
                BackupRect.Height = Convert.ToInt32(BackupRect.Height * 2.4);
                BackupRect.Y = Convert.ToInt32(LocationY * 2.3);

// Iterating through the file until there are no barcodes left.

                while (!Finished)
                {
                    if (BackupRect.Y <= WorkImage[PreviewIndex].Height)
                    {
                        if (!Fixing)
                        {
                            //Output.Add(Next);
/*
Ensuring the rectangle that is generated has the same starting point as the drawn rectangle.
*/
                            Rect.X = LocationX;
                            Rect.Y = LocationY;

                            //Drawing the rectangle around the barcode.

                            pen = new Pen(Color.Green);
                            G.DrawRectangle(pen, BackupRect);

                            PbPreview.Image = WorkImage[PreviewIndex];
                            BackupRect.Y += Convert.ToInt32(ItemAfstand * 2.3); //Increasing the distance to make the next rectangle go to the next barcode.
                        }
                        else
                        {
//For debugging. Can be ignored
                            BackupRect.Y = 500000;
                            //G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, FixtRect.Y, FixtRect.X, FixtRect.Width, FixtRect.Height);
                        }
                    }
                    else //Break the loop when the entire invoice has been processed.
                        {
                        Finished = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("Finished");
                        if (MessageBox.Show("Zijn alle barcodes correct geselecteerd?", "Waarschuwing", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Select the remaining barcodes using the debug rectangle.");
                            Fixing = true;
                            //pen = new Pen(Color.Pink);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Save the barcodes");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return Output;
        }
```

As mentioned prior, I start by drawing a rectangle and follow it up with a second rectangle to define the distance between two barcodes. Then, using these data, the program will generate the remaining rectangles. However, these rectangles don't appear in the location they should be at all. There appears to be a difference in "pixel" when it comes to image and rectangle.
[For reasons unknown, stackoverflow doesnt let me paste screenshots. If anyone can point me to a solution, I'd be happy to add my screenshots]

Many thanks in advance!
~Melvin

Comment: What is `PbPreview`? a PictureBox? If so: What Sizemode does it have? If not `Normal` you will need to convert/scale mouse coordinates..

Comment: It is a picture box yes. Sizemode is stretchimage. What should I base the conversion on then?

Comment: You need to find the scale factors for x and y separately and then use a function like this `PointF scaledPoint(PointF pt, float scale, bool unscale)
{
 if (unscale) return new PointF(pt.X / scaleX, pt.Y / scaleY);
    else return new PointF( pt.X * scaleY, (pt.Y * scaleY));
}`. To finde the two factors simply divide pb.Image.WightOrHeight by pb.WidthOr Height.. - See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027931/how-to-control-position-of-label-or-any-control-picturebox/35033334#35033334)

Comment: @TaW sorry for the late reply. Your solution worked for me, thanks. If you submit it as an answer I'll go ahead and mark it as accepted for you :)