# Problem with Scale matrix in canvas scene and mouse position [WinForms]

Tags: c#, winforms, canvas, gdi+, c#-6.0

After applying a scale matrix to my scene of drawable objects, the actual position in the mouse cursor scene is incorrect.

In my opinion the problem is caused by the location gave me from the event of control (mousedown,up,and move) that is not faithful to my scene geometry.

```
 var matrix = this.Control.Scene.Matrix.Inverse();
 this.CoordsLabel.Text = matrix.MultiplyPoint(e.Location).ToString()
```

When i m very zoommed in my scene, "matrix.MultiplyPoint(e.Location)" return the same value for a short mouse movement. The other operation like translation, rotation works fine.

Example Image:

[Here, The cursor is perfectly adjacent to the gray cross drawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYLQn.png)

[Here, This is very zoom situation, the cursor is not over the gray cross line, and for small mouse movement the gray line not change, as if the multiplication with scene matrix give me the same value of coord. (matrix.MultiplyPoint(e.Location))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzF5D.png)

Please hel me with this problem.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: _the location gave me from the event of control (mousedown,up,and move) that is not faithful to my scene geometry._ Indeed. It is returning the actual pixel coordinates of your control. You need to scale those like you did with the the graphics. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027931/how-to-control-position-of-label-or-any-control-picturebox/35033334#35033334)

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, i think that the problem is the float value calculate with the inverse of scene matrix.... because i have 2 system, one is the scene matrix and other is the system of every object, the absolute position is created with scene.matrix * object.matrix... if i have the mouse position in absolute system, the only way that i find is to multiply point with the inverse of scene.matrix...